# CodeIgniter Rewrite URL: remove index.php from url

Tags: codeigniter-2

My apps url is

```
http://localhost/myapp/admin/index.php/projects
```

and I want to rewrite it as

```
http://localhost/myapp/admin/projects
```

I followed user guide

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

for this but not work for me.

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: Did you remove `index.php` from the `index_page` variable in the config file as well?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove index.php from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344656/remove-index-php-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps:

1- If you work on localhost please enable mode_rewrite in php.ini

2- Create a .htaccess file under project folder and paste this (please change 'project' to your project folder name):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /project/index.php
</IfModule>
```

3- Edit this line at application/config.php:

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank /* ActuallyMAB */: Your code actually works. The above code works on localhost (WAMP Server on windows). 
If you have placed your codeigniter project in some folder such as your directory structure looks like:

```
C:\wamp\www\proposal
```

So, You have to replace

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project/index.php/$1 [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /proposal{or your folder name}/index.php/$1 [L]
```

if this is not the case with your project {you have put your codeigniter directly into www folder}, then remove the folder name from the above code as it looks like;

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

also do not forget to change

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

in your config folder {config.php}

I hope others have also provided the same answer, but since the above code works in my project and i felt to provide some details too.

Comment: I am sorry to ask this: I can not login to my website when i implemented the above code. I guess data is not being pulled or what is the issue.