# Codeigniter: getting clean urls and removing index.php

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Well I'm not really sure how you guys implement mod_rewrite with codeigniter, and I'm not even sure If I need to do that right now. What I want is to get rid of the index.php that trails the root directory, so eliminate it from www.mydomain.com/index.php/mycontroller and just have www.mydomain.com/mycontroller/

Comment: I answered it before, you can look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151477/codeigniter-rewrite-url-remove-index-php-from-url/11155387#11155387

Comment: This question has been answered numerous time in SO and there is a very good documentation in CI UserGuide to do so.. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can place this in .htaccess to remove index.php from url

```
    #### Remove index.php ###
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    #### index.php ###
```

Comment: This does not work in CI3, not sure about CI2 (but probably not). See solution below by Dan Teesdale for a working solution for CI3. You will also need to make the changes suggested by nageeb below. If your using apache you also need to enable mod_rewrite

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what everyone above said about .htaccess, you also have to set

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

in your /application/config/config.php file

Answer (score 2):

You can hide your index.php by modifying your .htaccess file. For example,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

You can find out more about CodeIgniter URLs here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html